# Issue azure test chat bot " Error while finding module specification for 'aiohttp.web' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp')

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, chatbot, aiohttp

I have some issues while trying to use azure test chat bot :

I deployed my bot on azure web app with github actions, everything is going great.
But when i'm trying to test my chatbot, nothing happens it throws me an error.

I tried to use differents python versions and also differents requirement version.
I have configured port 8000, app_id and password_id in my config.py file.

My web app has his general parameters configured with this command :

```
 python -m aiohttp.web -H 0.0.0.0 -P 8000 app:init_func
```

It seems that azure can't find aiohttp. (It works perfectly on local host )
Thank you for your help.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoBQJ.png) [app.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn1aj.png) [requirement.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMaEn.png)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it wasn't able to install requirements after the deploy.
The reason was that path wasn't good even if in the workflow there was a good path.

Solution :
I redeployed from another repo where the requirement.txt was in working directory.
After that i allowed cors with "*" to get all the the origins access.
I also blocked aiohttp to 3.6.2
I launch the webchat and it works
[new_requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjzRC.png) [CORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/412O1.png)